# Drag and Drop Cells in FlexTable in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, drag-and-drop, flextable

I want to implement a native drag and drop of widgets  of a FlexTable without using any third party library in GWT.Im looking for something similar to this
http://tech.pro/tutorial/688/javascript-tutorial-drag-drop-lists

this is in javascript i want to achieve the similar kind of functionality with GWT

I have looked into the answer provided by @BruceLowe over here
[Making a drag and drop FlexTable in GWT 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068506/making-a-drag-and-drop-flextable-in-gwt-2-5)

but its is missing a few classes namely  DragVerticalHandler and DraggableWidget classes so  the code is not working. Does anyone know how to achieve this

Comment: Why don't you want to use a third party library ?

Comment: If your hesitation is using a 3rd party lib that is wrapping js using native then this is not a problem. jdramaix has an excellent plugin for gwtquery called gwtquery dnd. It will compile your code and does not require an external js file.

Comment: Here are the examples. https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers#DragAndDropCellTable_,_DragAndDropDataGrid_and_DragAndDropColumn

Comment: thank you for the comment but I want the application to be self sufficient and want to introduce native drag and drop for the flex table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little Prototyping I was able to make a drag gable flextable.I created a class which extended the flex table.Here is the code

```
public class DragFlexTable extends FlexTable implements
            MouseDownHandler,MouseUpHandler,MouseMoveHandler,
            MouseOutHandler
{
    private int row,column,draggedrow,draggedcolumn;
    private Element td;
    private Widget w;
    private boolean emptycellclicked;
    DragFlexTable()
    {
        sinkEvents(Event.ONMOUSEOVER | Event.ONMOUSEOUT | Event.ONMOUSEDOWN | Event.ONMOUSEMOVE);
        this.addMouseDownHandler(this);
        this.addMouseMoveHandler(this);
        this.addMouseUpHandler(this);
        this.addMouseOutHandler(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event)
    {
        super.onBrowserEvent(event);
        td = getEventTargetCell(event);
        if (td == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Element tr = DOM.getParent((com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) td);
        Element body = DOM.getParent((com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) tr);
        row = DOM.getChildIndex((com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) body, (com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) tr);//(body, tr);
        column = DOM.getChildIndex((com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) tr, (com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) td);
    }
    boolean mousedown;
    @Override
    public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getNativeButton() == NativeEvent.BUTTON_LEFT)
        {
            //to ensure empty cell is not clciked
            if (!td.hasChildNodes())
            {
                emptycellclicked = true;
            }
            event.preventDefault();
            start(event);
            mousedown = true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event)
    {
        if (mousedown)
        {
            drag(event);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onMouseUp(MouseUpEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getNativeButton() == NativeEvent.BUTTON_LEFT)
        {
            if (!emptycellclicked)
            {
                end(event);
            }
            emptycellclicked = false;
            mousedown = false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event)
    {
        this.getCellFormatter().getElement(row, column).getStyle().clearBorderStyle();
        this.getCellFormatter().getElement(row, column).getStyle().clearBorderColor();
        this.getCellFormatter().getElement(row, column).getStyle().clearBorderWidth();
        w.getElement().getStyle().setOpacity(1);
        mousedown = false;
    }
    private void start(MouseDownEvent event)
    {
        w = this.getWidget(row, column);
        w.getElement().getStyle().setOpacity(0.5);
    }
    private void drag(MouseMoveEvent event)
    {
        if (draggedrow != row || draggedcolumn != column)
        {
            this.getCellFormatter().getElement(draggedrow, draggedcolumn).getStyle().clearBorderStyle();
            this.getCellFormatter().getElement(draggedrow, draggedcolumn).getStyle().clearBorderColor();
            this.getCellFormatter().getElement(draggedrow, draggedcolumn).getStyle().clearBorderWidth();
            this.draggedrow = row;
            this.draggedcolumn = column;
            this.getCellFormatter().getElement(row, column).getStyle().setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.DASHED);
            this.getCellFormatter().getElement(row, column).getStyle().setBorderColor("black");
            this.getCellFormatter().getElement(row, column).getStyle().setBorderWidth(2, Unit.PX);
        }
    }
    private void end(MouseUpEvent event)
    {
        insertDraggedWidget(row, column);
    }
    private void insertDraggedWidget(int r,int c)
    {
        this.getCellFormatter().getElement(r, c).getStyle().clearBorderStyle();
        this.getCellFormatter().getElement(r, c).getStyle().clearBorderColor();
        this.getCellFormatter().getElement(r, c).getStyle().clearBorderWidth();
        w.getElement().getStyle().setOpacity(1);
        if (this.getWidget(r, c) != null)
        {
            //pushing down the widgets already in the column 
            //          int widgetheight = (this.getWidget(r, c).getOffsetHeight() / 2) + this.getWidget(r, c).getAbsoluteTop();
            //          int rw;
            //placing the widget above the dropped widget
            for (int i = this.getRowCount() - 1; i >= r; i--)
            {
                if (this.isCellPresent(i, c))
                {
                    this.setWidget(i + 1, c, this.getWidget(i, c));
                }
            }
        }
        this.setWidget(r, c, w);
        //removes unneccesary blank rows 
        cleanupRows();
        //pushing up the column in the stack
        //      for (int i = oldrow;i<this.getRowCount()-1 ;i++)
        //      {
        //          
        //              this.setWidget(i ,oldcolumn, this.getWidget(i+1, oldcolumn));
        //          
        //      }
    }
    private void cleanupRows()
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> rowsfilled = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= this.getRowCount() - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= this.getCellCount(i) - 1; j++)
            {
                if (this.getWidget(i, j) != null)
                {
                    rowsfilled.add(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //replace the empty rows
        for (int i = 0; i < rowsfilled.size(); i++)
        {
            int currentFilledRow = rowsfilled.get(i);
            if (i != currentFilledRow)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < this.getCellCount(currentFilledRow); j++)
                {
                    this.setWidget(i, j, this.getWidget(currentFilledRow, j));
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = rowsfilled.size(); i < this.getRowCount(); i++)
        {
            this.removeRow(i);
        }
    }
    public HandlerRegistration addMouseUpHandler(MouseUpHandler handler)
    {
        return addDomHandler(handler, MouseUpEvent.getType());
    }
    public HandlerRegistration addMouseDownHandler(MouseDownHandler handler)
    {
        return addDomHandler(handler, MouseDownEvent.getType());
    }
    public HandlerRegistration addMouseMoveHandler(MouseMoveHandler handler)
    {
        return addDomHandler(handler, MouseMoveEvent.getType());
    }
    public HandlerRegistration addMouseOutHandler(MouseOutHandler handler)
    {
        return addDomHandler(handler, MouseOutEvent.getType());
    }
}
```

and the on module load for the above custom widget is

```
public void onModuleLoad()
    {
        Label a = new Label("asad");
        Label b = new Label("ad");
        Label c = new Label("qwad");
        Label w = new Label("zxd");
        a.setPixelSize(200, 200);
        a.getElement().getStyle().setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.SOLID);
        a.getElement().getStyle().setBorderWidth(1, Unit.PX);
        b.setPixelSize(200, 200);
        c.setPixelSize(200, 200);
        w.setPixelSize(200, 200);
        a.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("red");
        b.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("yellowgreen");
        c.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("lightblue");
        w.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("grey");
        DragFlexTable d = new DragFlexTable();
        d.setWidget(0, 0, a);
        d.setWidget(0, 1, b);
        d.setWidget(1, 0, c);
        d.setWidget(1, 1, w);
        d.setCellPadding(20);
        RootPanel.get().add(d);
    }
```